# Display first in the system tray

Tags: c#, notifications

I use a notify icon to create a small program. Unfortunately, it only appears after pressing the small arrow in the bottom right corner of the taskbar. Is there a way to display it on the first line?

Answer (score 1):

The positioning of the notify icon in windows can be determined by the user. You can just move the icon with drag & drop into the taskbar and it should automatically reappear in the taskbar, if you restart your application.

Answer (score 0):

You can drag and drop these icons yourself (i.e. you can drag the icon to the always visible portion and it will stay there).

If you're asking how to do this programmatically, I'm not sure of a way to do so. [According to this answer on superuser it looks like you can update a registry key to rearrange these, but proceed with caution.](https://superuser.com/a/520701)